# Run Amazon device messaging on android virtual device

Tags: android, amazon-device-messaging

I have bug with amazon device messaging.

compile in gradle:

```
//compile in gradle
provided files('libs/amazon-device-messaging-1.0.1.jar')
```

I've been tried:

compile files('libs/amazon-device-messaging-1.0.1.jar')

manifest:

```
<permission android:name="com.bookmark.money.permission.RECEIVE_ADM_MESSAGE"
android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission      android:name="com.bookmark.money.permission.RECEIVE_ADM_MESSAGE" />

 <uses-permission android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging.permission.RECEIVE" />

 <application ...>

<amazon:enable-feature
   android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging"
   android:required="true" />

</application>
```

call ADM:

```
//call adm
ADM adm = new ADM(context); //error inline
```

in logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.amazon.device.messaging.ADM
                  at com.zoostudio.moneylover.cloudMessage.CloudMessageHelper.getCloudMessageId(CloudMessageHelper.java:21)
                  at com.zoostudio.moneylover.cloudMessage.CloudMessageHelper.register(CloudMessageHelper.java:14)
                  at com.zoostudio.moneylover.MoneyApplication.createObjectSingleton(MoneyApplication.java:511)
                  at com.zoostudio.moneylover.MoneyApplication.onCreate(MoneyApplication.java:294)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1000)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4391)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1294)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)'
```

Please help me if you have any ideas!

*Update:

Levon from Amazon reply for me. ADM can run on physical device (of Amazon or not) but not work :(

same error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/amazon/device/messaging/ADM;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue. Problem was in xml namespace in manifest.

It should be like in [documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/adm/integrate-your-app.html):

> xmlns:amazon="http://schemas.amazon.com/apk/res/android"​